# How to get the returned php page in json format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to get the contents of the returned php page, as follows:

```
(<?php echo json_encode(array("color"=>"Red")); ?>)
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
;
    $.get("page.php", 
        function(data){
            $('body').append("Color: " + data.color)
    }, "json");
;
</script>
```

My page.php:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("color"=>"Red")); ?>
```

How to make it work?

Comment: So what problem are you actually having? This looks like it should be fine. Can you look in net panel in Firebug or similar to see what response you are actually getting from the server?

Comment: Well i've just discovered you can actually append text. Who would have thought it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php    
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("color"=>"Red"));
die;
```

Comment: @ popnoodles, and all the other, I’m sorry… I tested it out on old version of IE. It works.

Comment: If the file doesn't end in .json IE is like "DAFUQ IS THAT?"